# String with null-character

Tags: rascal, null-character

Suppose we have the two lexical definitions:

```
  lexical DQChr = ![\"] | [\"][\"];
  lexical String = "\"" DQChr* "\"";
```

Then the following cases parse well:

```
  parse(#String,"\"a\"");
  parse(#String,"\"\u0001\"");
```

However, the null-character gives a parse error:

```
  parse(#String,"\u0000");
```

*How can I allow a null-character in my quoted string?*

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can just add `\u0000` to the regex:

```
Version: 0.28.2
rascal>lexical DQChr = ([\u0000] | ![\"]) | [\"][\"];
ok
rascal>lexical String = "\"" DQChr* "\"";
ok
rascal>parse(#String,"\"a\"");
String: (String) `"a"`
rascal>parse(#String,"\"\u0001\"");
String: (String) `""`
rascal>parse(#String,"\"\u0000\"");
String: (String) `""`
```

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick. I am still a bit puzzled why the null-character was not allowed, but at least I can move on.

Comment: As a side remark, quoted strings normally do not contain null characters, if they do then somewhere in the process they got inserted which may not have been intended - so while there are valid uses, I'd say it does make sense to disallow these characters in strings.

Comment: I have to parse legacy Cobol code which happens to contain these string constants with null-characters, so I cannot disallow these cases.

Comment: It's an obscure semantics of the character class negation to exclude the 0 character, so `![]` becomes `[\u0001-\uFFFF]` and not `[\u0000-\uFFFF]`. The underlying reason is that meta variables in concrete syntax always start and end with a 0 character, and the use of `![]` would then accidentally always lead to ambiguity in concrete syntax patterns.

Comment: So the semantics of `![]` explains @StevenKlusener 's puzzel.

Comment: I would use character class union to avoid stack operations during long string parsing as follows: `lexical Q = (![] || [\u0000])`. By using `||` the character classes will be merged into `[\u0000-\uFFFF]` at parser generation time. On the contrary the single `|` will keep the disjunction separate until parse time, and predict both sides at every character position in the string constant only to throw the other away again.